# c++ template function, exclude a line in template function for a certain type

Tags: c++, templates

In C++, I have a template function which takes an operation type as the type.

The types are operations types in a neural network for example a convolution, depthwise convolution or a MaxPool.

The purpose of the function is to build the operation in 3 steps (1) build the input tensor (2) build the weights tensor and (3) build the output tensor.

But depending on the type, sometimes I want to skip step 2.

For example, maxpool does not have weights so I do not want to build a weights tensor.

Is there anyway to acheive this.

```
template <class OpType>
void Manager::buildoperation(OpType& operation) const {
   //Step 1:
   const auto inputTensor = buildInputTensor(operation);
   
   // Step 2. Skip this step if OpType == Maxpool
   const auto weightsTensor = buildWeightsTensor(operation);
 
    //Step 3:
   const auto outputTensor = buildOutputTensor(operation);
}
```

The method buildWeightsTensor() contains code that is not applicable i.e. methods that are not available to MaxPool so it breaks compilation.

The project that I'm using requires C++ 14.

Comment: Use either a template specialization or if constexpr since C++17.

Comment: @273K unfortunately I can only use C++14. Would you have an example of template specialization?